# How to send code written in code editor to server using POST method

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http

I'm working on building a snippet manager app and through the interface you can create new snippets and edit them using a code editor but what I'm stuck at is how can I send the snippet code to my server using POST for it to create a new file for that snippet.

For ex. -

```js
const getUser = async (name) => {
  let response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${name}`);
  let data = await response.json()
  return data;
}
```

One solution that I can think of is to parse the code into JSON equivalent that'll contain all the tokens in JSON format but for that I'll have to add parsers for every language and select a parser based on what language the user selected. I'm trying to figure out a way to avoid having to add all the parsers unless there isnt any solution for this.

Another solution I can think of is to generate the file from the frontend and send that file through POST request.

My current stack is Node+React

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the second solution is working for me right now. I've written the code below for it -

```js
app.post("/create", isFileAttached, function(req, res) {
  const { file } = req.files;
  const saveLocation = `${saveTo}/${file.mimetype.split("/")[1]}`;
  const savePath = `${saveLocation}/${file.name}`;
  if (!fs.existsSync(saveLocation)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(saveLocation, { recursive: true });
  }
  fs.writeFile(savePath, file.data.toString(), err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.status(200).send({ message: "The file has been saved!" });
  });
});
```

With this solution I no longer have to add any parsers, since whatever's written in the files are no longer a concern anymore.